# how to invoke a function written in one user control from another user control?

Tags: asp.net

I have two user controls I have some functions written on those two controls. Is it possible to invoke a function written on one user control from another user control. Pls provide the code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good only when one user control is always contained in another. Other wise you don't know if both controls exists on the page. It is best to use the containing page as a mediator to call the methods (don't know what this pattern is called). to call methods in User Control from an asp.net page you need to write public/internal methods in user control and simply call it on instance of user control in page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to raise an event from one control and handle it in the other. Here is a good example for this. http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2007/08/23/raise-event-from-user-control-to-main-page-event-delegation-from-user-control-to-aspx-page-in-aspnetc/

Answer (score 0):

There is an addition to the answers above:

if the method (I only know C#, this is why I write method) you want to call is static (or can be made static), you can "just call it" (i.e. you do not need an instance of the class): `SomeWebControl.StaticMethodToCall` should do it.